# Android Kotlin retrieve context from an object

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey I'm using Android Studio with Kotlin and I have an activity and a service that both needs to call same methods, so I created an object with theses methods in it, which would be like a utils class.

The problem is that the methods depend on a field that needs the application context to be created, and the only way I found to retrieve the context was to pass it through the constructor, but as it's an object I can't do that.

How could I keep that object behaviour and retrieve the application context ?

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, an object behaves like a static util class(not exactly at bytecode level) so there are only a few options that you could do

1. Pass the the context in every util method in the object which needs the context
2. Make an `Application` class and keep a global reference of the application context and use it everywhere by making it `lateinit var` and initialising it in `Application``s `onCreate` method
3. Or use DI for injection of Application context and instead of using Object use Singleton scoped utility that is injected everywhere

Comment: You could also add it as a ``lateinit var`` and make sure you initialise it early (like in the ``Application``'s ``onCreate`` - just before anything tries to use the context-requiring methods

Comment: @cactustictacs Thanks for clarification. Actually, my point meant what you are saying. But anyway I have included your comments as well